# Calculate the limit of logarithm functions

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate limit expressed by:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{x\ln(x)}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking ln of both sides, you obtain, for $x\to+\infty$:
\begin{equation}
x\ln(x)\ln\left(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)\sim x\ln(x)\left(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}-1\right)=\frac{x\ln(x)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}\right)\sim \frac{x\ln(x)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\left(\frac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}-1\right)=
\frac{x\ln(x)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}\right)\sim \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\sim \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x^2)}\to\frac 12.
\end{equation}
Thus your limit is $\sqrt e$.